# Link resolving in Rich text field

Tags: dxa, rtf, sites-9.5, link-resolver

We have special request from business

1. Content will be created content publication
2. Content Publication is inheriting to two different website publications like full site and thin site shown as in blue print
   [image]
3. Component links are added in Rich text field in 200 content publication
4. Those components have pages in 500 Full website publication and those links are working as expected in 600 Full website language publication websites.
5. Where as components don't have pages in 500 Thin website publication.
6. That is the reason links are not resolving in 600 thin website language publication websites
7. Business is requesting the links should be resolved to 500 Full website publication website pages.
8. What will be the best approach? Can we use custom resolver in this case or Event System?

Answer (score 1):

I think good approaches depend on how you publish and render markup for the Thin Website.

If using Content Manager templating with .NET or Java in delivery, then consider using Template Building Blocks and perhaps custom Tridion Content Delivery Language (TCDL) tags to change how the component links resolve in rich text format area fields.

However, if using templateless data publishing, it'll be better to change the link behavior either in Content Delivery (again, custom TCDL tags) or in the application directly.

See the RWS Documentation Center for [information about the TCDL tags](https://docs.rws.com/816112/103440/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/creating-custom-tcdl-tags).

I don't think a Custom Resolver or Event System would be a good fit since the link resolving happens in Content Delivery or the web application and the content should be the same between Publications. Otherwise an Event System approach would force you to localize content in one or both of the publications, defeating the idea of reusing the links. :-)